# firebase cloud functions - pub/sub triggers - what is the delay between publishing and subscriber function to be executed

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

**Use case :**

I have a webhook which handles incoming slack messages. I have to respond to that webhook with 200 OK status within 300 ms otherwise it will retry hitting my webhook again.

The webhook is basically a http firebase cloud function. I have to process the incoming webhook immediately without any delays. the processing will be more than 300 ms most of the times which is leading to multiple hits on my webhook although i returned a 200OK status.

what i was doing till now was immediately saving the incoming webhook's payload to a firestore collection and handling the processing in onCreate of the document. But onCreate takes a few seconds to be triggered which is unacceptable in our case. I am not sure if this is because of cold-start.

I want to see if I can use pub/sub triggers for this. The following are my doubts

1. How much time does it take to publish to the topic
2. How much delay is there after I publish to the topic and the subscriber function starts executing. If this has the same delay as of onCreate then this won't work.

If this doesn't work what is the best way to proceed?

Comment: Another  approach would be to hit cloud-tasks telling it to hit another one of our http cloud function to process the message. Not sure how much delay this will cause too.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud tasks are pretty quick to respond. I've used them to call the server again to process time consuming tasks such as uploading content submitted by user to the user to something like Cloud Storage or any CDN.

You can actually set the duration in how long the Google Task should trigger. Using it with [Cloud Compute](https://cloud.google.com/compute) the trigger is almost instantaneous. In Cloud functions, the worst case scenario would be a cold start but that should be rare if you keep invoking them frequently. Just set the timeout for cloud tasks to 0 and it's call your function immediately. But again, sometimes Cloud Compute may be a better choice than Cloud Functions.

Comment: Yes this is one way, i was hoping if this could be totally done with pub-sub triggers for cloud functions in firebase.

Comment: @CommandSpace it can be. I just gave an example of Google Tasks because I have used it hands on and I'm sure that way works. But yes using pub/sub will be none or less the same. I just like tasks as they will retry to run same function is they receive an error and not 2XX response.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you’d like to respond to incoming Slack webhook requests with HTTP 200 OK in under 300ms while durably triggering downstream computation. Your proposed use of Cloud Pub/Sub is to publish the webhook contents to a topic, respond to the webhook request immediately and trigger a [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions) for the computation using the Pub/Sub topic.

This is a reasonable solution. While Cloud Pub/Sub does not offer an SLA on latency, the service is optimized for low [publish latency](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/architecture#latency) and so most requests will be successfully handled in the 300ms envelope provided the [Publisher object](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/publisher#publishing_messages) is already initialized and reused. The actual delivery of messages to the function can take slightly longer, but if there is a consistent flow of messages it should be within 1-2 seconds. Please note that Pub/Sub guarantees at-least-once deliveries which means the function may be triggered multiple times for the same message so your processing logic should be idempotent.